# Replace dynamic string value in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to replace a dynamic value of a string:

My dynamic value is resulOffset=**25**

I tried like this:

```
var str = 'http://example.com?resultLimit=25&resulOffset=25';

var resultOffset = 50;

var newOffset = str.replace(/(resultOffset=)([0-9]+)/, '$1' + resultOffset);    

console.log(newOffset);
```

but doesn't work. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here: `var str = 'http://example.com?resultLimit=25&resulOffset=25';`

you have `resulOffset` instead of `resultOffset`.

Answer (score 3):

try this one,

```
var str = 'http://example.com?resultLimit=25&resulOffset={0}';

var resultOffset = 50;

 var newOffset = str.replace('{0}',resultOffset);

 console.log(newOffset);
```